# Prove that $ \lim_{N\to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left[\cos \left( n\Delta \right)\right]^2}{N} = \frac{1}{2} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Prove that

$$ 
\lim_{N\to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left[\cos \left( n\Delta \right)\right]^2}{N}  = \frac{1}{2},  {\quad \rm for\ } {m\pi} \neq \Delta \in \mathbb{R}, \quad m \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

and that

$$ 
\lim_{N\to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left[\sin\left( n\Delta \right)\right]^2}{N}  = \frac{1}{2},  {\quad \rm for\ } {m\pi}\neq\Delta  \in \mathbb{R}, \quad m \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

PS: I have verified the above identities using MATLAB, but I fail to prove them completely with "proper" math skills.

Comment: Minor point: It would be more appropriate to write "$0 \neq \Delta \in \Bbb R$" instead.

Comment: A similar result can be shown for the series where sine/cosine are not squared, and the typical proof of that (e.g. [here](https://is.gd/YHvZZo)) usually hinges on the facts that
$$\begin{align*}
e^{i \theta} &= \cos \theta + i \sin \theta\\
\Re(e^{i \theta}) &= \cos \theta\\
\Im(e^{i \theta}) &= \sin \theta\\
\Re(z_1 + z_2) &= \Re(z_1) + \Re(z_2) \\
\Im(z_1 + z_2) &= \Im(z_1) + \Im(z_2)
\end{align*}$$
You usually start with the finite series using just $e^{i \theta}$, and play with the real/imaginary parts as necessary and get the end result. I imagine something similar can work here.

Comment: Also, the second identity seems to be weird. Shouldn't you get $0$ whenever $\Delta$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$? (Similarly, the first identity should be $1$.)

Comment: To couple with @EeveeTrainer's hint: Recall that $$\cos^2\theta = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2\theta)),$$ $$\sin^2\theta = \frac{1}{2}(-1 + \cos(2\theta)).$$

Comment: You can also note that it suffices to simply solve one of the two limits. If one is $L$, the other is $1 - L$. In particular, this shows that there's something weird about your conditions on $\Delta$.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani Yes. $\Delta \neq i\pi, i = 0, 1, \cdots$, not only 0

Comment: @Lázaro Albuquerque I have the same thinking in the very beginning, but I tried with MATLAB and it works for any $\Delta$ (rational or irrational)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first one. With a few manipulations we have the sum is equal to

$$S = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N 1 + \cos(2n\Delta)}{2N} = \frac{1}{2}+\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\operatorname{Re}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{2in\Delta}\right\} = \frac{1}{2}+\lim_{N\to\infty}\operatorname{Re}\left\{\frac{e^{i2\Delta}}{N}\frac{e^{2iN\Delta}-1}{e^{2i\Delta}-1}\right\}$$

$$= \frac{1}{2} + \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\cos(2N\Delta)}{2N}+\frac{\cot(\Delta)}{2N}+\frac{\cos(2\Delta)}{4N\sin^2(\Delta)}$$

which converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ precisely when the terms on the right are bounded i.e. $\sin(\Delta) \neq 0$. What will always be true regardless of the value of $\Delta$ is that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N \cos^2(n\Delta)}{N} + \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N \sin^2(n\Delta)}{N} = 1$$

so if you know one, you can find the other.

Comment: Using your method, I finally reach a different result $$ \frac{1}{2} -\lim_{N\to +\infty} \Big[ \frac{1}{4N} + \frac{\cos(2(N+1)\Delta)}{8N\sin^2\Delta} - \frac{\cos(2N\Delta)}{8N\sin^2\Delta} \Big]$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution. But this compiles the ideas from the comments which will lead to the solution.

1. Note that since $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ for all $\theta \in \Bbb R$, it suffices to solve just the first limit. If that is $L$, then the second limit is $1 - L$.
2. Let us concentrate on the first limit. Note that $$\cos^2\theta = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2\theta)).$$
3. The question is now simplified to solving $$\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^N \cos(2n\Delta).$$
4. Note that angles in the cosine in the sum form an arithmetic progression. Thus, you can evaluate the sum explicitly, see answers and formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro). (Be careful in applying the formula by considering when $\Delta$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.)
   Actually, all you need from the formula is the fact that the summation is bounded with the bound only depending on $\Delta$ (and not $N$).

---

I'll point out that your result, as stated, is incorrect. It will fail precisely when $\Delta$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$. In that case, the first limit is $1$ (and hence, the second is $0$).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the conditions under which the equations are not valid. I have edited my statement, plz see the updated question.

Comment: @gulugulu: Your update makes it correct. Regardless, my answer still stands as it is.